# touchpad not working in ubuntu 14.04 (dual booted pc)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, touchpad, synaptics, toshiba-satellite

My pc (Toshiba Satellite) is dual booted with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. Last week it didn't boot ubuntu and the touchpad stopped working. However I solved the booting problems (It now boots both os). But the touch pad is still not working (in both os). Please help me fix this.